# on Post request triggered python script

Tags: python, http

im trying to create a python script , that will listen to url that i generated in power automate
, i want to POST some message to this url , and the script should on POST request show windows message with posted message

i tried with something like that but this doesnt work.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/https://prod-210.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/h42pyg6hri09ia8ld635rihqmnxan7/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=iVBrh1DS6QGgUSQ-jjy2s7kppWg1--XvmbWjK4UzNPg', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    # Perform your desired action here
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    return 'Request received successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This doesnt work either:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/workflows/45g4e5grte45hbvcberter345346/triggers/manual/paths/invoke', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    # Perform your desired action here
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    return 'Request received successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='prod-210.westeurope.logic.azure.com', port=443, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Comment: Your `app.route` commands take **paths** as arguments, not **urls**. So you can route to `/` or `/workflows`, etc, but the hostname and so forth are managed outside of Flask.